# Install ONLY mongo shell, not mongodb

Tags: mongodb, shell, rhel

As mentioned above, I need to install only the mongo shell on a RHEL instance (machine A).
I have a mongodb server on a separate instance (machine B) and need to connect to that from A to run `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands.

I tried looking it up on the web but all I got was instructions to install the complete mongodb package.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/) says that you should be fine installing `mongodb-org-shell` only.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed that!

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn , If the O.S will be windows then how we install the 'mongo shell' there.

Comment: On Windows I am unaware of a way to install separate components.

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn yes you can install just the client tools on Windows, the docs are a bit confusing. It mentions that you can set those options on the unattended install - but not on the interactive. However, when you run the interactive it gives you the options to limit it to just the client tools.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I am getting a not found for this package.

Comment: The package appears to be called mongodb-clients on Ubuntu now

Comment: And now it's called 'mongo-tools'

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a repository file at `sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo`

> ```
> [mongodb-org-4.0]
> name=MongoDB Repository 
> baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
> gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
> gpgcheck=1 
> enabled=1
> ```

2. `sudo yum clean all`
3. `sudo yum install mongodb-org-shell-4.0.2`
4. `mongo <mongo-server-ip>` Note: Step 4 will not work in all cases. You need to check proper command to connect to remote mongo server.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the [official tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/) on installing `mongodb`, and instead of installing the main package that will install all the packages, just install the package containing mongoshell

Comment: Thanks! I am choosing the other answer as correct as it is more explicit on the name of the package.

Comment: apologies for the same. Will persevere to be more diligent in the future. :)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to [install](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/) `mongosh` (MongoDB Shell) instead. The legacy `mongo` shell has been [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) since MongoDB v5.0 and replaced by `mongosh`. From the [mongosh docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell):

> The new MongoDB Shell, `mongosh`, offers numerous advantages over the
> legacy mongo shell, such as:
>
> - Improved syntax highlighting.
> - Improved command history.
> - Improved logging.
>
> Currently mongosh supports a subset of the mongo shell
> methods. Achieving feature parity between mongosh and the mongo shell
> is an ongoing effort.
>
> To maintain backwards compatibility, the methods that mongosh supports
> use the same syntax as the corresponding methods in the mongo shell.
> To see the complete list of methods supported by mongosh, see [MongoDB
> Shell Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/methods/).

Further reference: [Compatibility Changes with Legacy mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps.

1. Create a file /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
2. Update the above file to contain:

   ```
   [mongodb]
   name=MongoDB Repository  
   baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/  
   gpgcheck=0
   enabled=1
   ```
3. `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-shell-2.6.9`
4. `mongo mongo-db_server_IP:27017/database_name -u username -p password`

Answer (score 0):

Head to [Mongo download](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server) page; download your required package regarding your operating system. Finally follow the instruction of your operating system to install the package.

Especially to install `mongo` or `mongosh`:

1. download `.tgz` file and untar the file into `/usr/local/`
2. add `/usr/local/mongo/` into the shell profile (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) and restart your terminal

For more information read the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/).

P.S.: `mongo` in the path should be vary based on the version of the downloaded package.