# Install mongo shell in mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, shell, homebrew

i wanted to install only `mongo-shell` in my mac

i ran `brew update` and then i ran `brew install mongodb-org-shell` .. But it is not getting installed. Below is the error message

```sh
bash-3.2$ brew install mongodb-org-shell 
Error: No available formula with the name "mongodb-org-shell" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From what I found on [MongoDB HomeBrew](https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew), to install only the Mongo Shell you should use:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

After that, install the shell:

```
brew install mongosh
```

For reference, the example below is no longer recommended ([deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 in 2021](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/#the-mdb-shell-versus-the-legacy-mongo-shell)):

```
brew install mongodb-community-shell
```

Answer (score 9):

You might want to [install](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/) `mongosh` (MongoDB Shell) instead. The legacy `mongo` shell has been [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongo) since MongoDB v5.0 and replaced by `mongosh`. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70565792/3972890).

Answer (score 1):

Install mongosh via brew:

```
brew install mongosh
```

Start mongosh using 'ships' database on specified connection string:

```
mongosh mongodb://192.168.0.5:9999/ships
```